# increase the integer value of 1 with Regex

Tags: regex

I want to increase value.For Example

- Jerry1
- Jerry2
- Jerry3
- Jerry4

I want to change that.

- Jerry2
- Jerry3
- Jerry4
- Jerry5

How can I change ?

Comment: iterate through each line, extract number, increment with one. Why use Regex?

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to **abuse regular expressions** for everything.

**By design, regular expressions are meant to not support counting**. The reason is simple: if you want to have this, you need at least a type-2 language, while processing is signficiantly more complex than for type 3 ("regular") languages.

See Wikipedia for details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy

So by the definition, once you fully support counting it probably no longer is a regular language.

There are extensions around, for example perl extended regular expressions, that do allow to solve this particular problem. But essentially, they are no longer regular expressions, but they invoke an external function to do the work.

The following **perl extended regular expression** should do what you want:

```
s/(-?\d+)/$1 + 1/eg
```

but essentially, only the matching part is a regular expression, the substitution is Perl, so turing complete. The `e` flag indicates the right part should be evaluated by Perl, not as regexp substitution string.

You can of course do this trick in pretty much any other regular expression engine. Match, then compute the increment, then substitute the match with the new value.

Full perl filter demo:

```
> echo 'Test 123 test 0 Banana9 -17 3 route66' | perl -pe 's/(-?\d+)/$1+1/eg'
Test 124 test 1 Banana10 -16 4 route67
```

The `p` flag makes perl read standard input and apply the program to each line, then output the result. That is why the actual script consists of the substitution only. This is what makes Perl so popular for unix scripting. You can even mass-apply this filter to a whole set of files (see `-i` for in-place modification, and the `perlrun` manual page). So in order to modify a whole set of files in place (backups will be postfixed with `.bak`):

```
perl -p -i .bak -e 's/(-?\d+)/$1+1/eg' <filenames>
```

Comment: Thank you for everything.I like that.